# How to filter out nodes using libxml2

Tags: c++, xml, xpath, libxml2

Given an XML document and an XPath expression, I want to create a new document which has all of the nodes of the original document *with the exception* of the nodes selected by the XPath expression, effectively giving the result of a subtract filter.

My idea was to use the `xmlXpathEvalExpression()` function, and for each node in the root document tree, copy the node over unless the node matches the returned `xmlNodeSet`. However, libxml2 gives no hints about how, or even if, nodes can be tested for equality.

Are you supposed to compare the pointers to the nodes in the returned set? Or are you supposed to compare the given node names/namespaces?

Comment: AFAIK, the node pointers in the XPath result set are pointing at the original nodes of the queried XML document.  So you should be able to do simple pointer comparisons.

Comment: That's what I've been thinking, but there's nothing about it in the documentation and nobody has ever said it outright, so I'm afraid that I would be using some implementation detail that could change in the future.

Comment: XPath is meant to be used for searching a document, so it doesn't make sense for the result set to point to *copies* of the nodes, that would just be wasted overhead, but rather to point to the *original* nodes instead. I don't see that changing anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the node pointers returned from evaluating an XPath expression point directly to the nodes in the original document.<sup>[1]</sup> So you can simply call `xmlUnlinkNode` on each node in the returned node set to remove it from the document. Then, in a second step, call `xmlFreeNode` on each node to free the nodes. It's important to not call `xmlFreeNode` before all nodes are unlinked.<sup>[2]</sup>

[1] Except for namespace nodes returned from the namespace axis `namespace::*` with type `XML_NAMESPACE_DECL`, but these are rarely used.

[2] It should work to immediately free each node if you iterate the node set in reverse order.